# Prestashop 1.5 - override confirmation email template

Tags: overriding, prestashop-1.5

I'll try to override mails/fr/order_conf.html

I'll try like this : 
override/themes/default/mails/fr/order_conf.html

But it doesn't works.
Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I made my change in order_conf.html and i placed into override/themes/default/mails/fr/order_conf.html. There is no error, just my change is not in the mail

Comment: if I chnage mails/fr/order_conf.html it works fine!

Comment: try adding that information and your code and the error message to your question...  maybe someone will then be able to help you

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution. 
To override the mails in prestashop, you need to copie de folder root/mails/
into your root/themes/your_theme_name/

Like this you can modify the mails look and It will ne not lost when you upgrade your prestashop.

I hope it can help...
bye